# How to add the actual size of the frequency of barplots in r with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to add the actual numbers above each bar.
I tried this but wasn't working. How should I fix that?
MP1 is an SPSS file, TBI and mp_1 are mutated factors.

```
ggplot(MP1) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=TBI), fill=mp_1))+
  geom_text(aes(label=count), vjust=1.5, colour="white", size=3.5)
```

Comment: Why isn't it working? What are you seeing and what do you want to see? What else have you tried? And if you can provide a bit of your data (10 or 20 rows at most), that will help others test their solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you have some typos/syntax issues, e.g. an extra ")" at the end of the `geom_bar()` line, and no `stat = "count"` in your `geom_text()`. Here is a reproducible example using the mtcars dataset which illustrates a potential solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cyl)) +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(x = cyl, label = ..count..), 
            vjust = 1.5, colour = "white", size = 3.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I can't test the solution out with your data as you haven't provided any (please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)), however my guess for your situation is:

```
ggplot(MP1) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=TBI), fill="dodgerblue"))+
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(x=TBI, label=..count..), vjust=1.5, colour="white", size=3.5)
```

In order to create a stacked barplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(fill = factor(gear), x = factor(carb))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "stack") + 
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count..),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Just another question, what should I write if I want to have a stacked plot and I want to show the number of each category of each bar on them?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show an example of a stacked boxplot